# Want app to execute some code when phone is plugged in and source determined to be a PC (not AC plug)

Tags: android, android-intent

**Problem:**

I am trying to write an app that executes some code when the phone is plugged into a power source which is determined to be a PC, as opposed to an AC port. I also want this app to have a gui interface which the user can "force" start that same code.

I have 2 classes so far: one is the main activity and the other one is a class that extends BroadcastReceiver.

**Code is below:**

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void func1(View view){ //stuff        }

    public void func2(View view){ //stuff        }
}
```

ChargingOnReceiver.java

```
public class ChargingOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CharSequence text = "Plug status = " + isUSBConnected(context);
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
    public static boolean isUSBConnected(Context context){
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <receiver android:name=".ChargingOnReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

*Side Question:*

So a quick first question: How can I call methods in MainActivity from ChargingOnReceiver (e.g. func1 or fucn2)? For example, my isUSBConnected() function used to be in MainActivity but I couldn't find a way to call it from ChargingOnReceiver so I moved it to ChargingOnReceiver.

**Main Question:**

The code errors out with:
**FATAL EXCEPTION: main:: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.ChargingOnReceiver: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
**

I kind of understand why it is erroring out, as I'm trying to register a receiver within a receiver, but could someone point me in the direction of how I would be able to do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

use:

```
context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

This is annoying -- `registerReceiver()` should be smarter than this -- but it's the workaround for this particular case.

Comment: Thanks greatly of the answer, works perfectly. I could have sworn I tried this exact solution/workaround (I'm pretty sure it was also you who suggested this on someone else's post on here when I was searching), but go figure, I must have changed something while trying to debug.

Comment: Also, since I really want to understand what's going on behind the scenes and not just get my bad code to work, could you point me in the direction of some information about why I ran into this problem and what was wrong exactly?

Comment: @Chris: Well, it's pretty much what the error message says: a `BroadcastReceiver` cannot register another `BroadcastReceiver`. In this case, you really *aren't* registering another `BroadcastReceiver` -- you are passing in `null` -- but `BroadcastReceiver` ignores that and complains anyway.

Comment: respect...CommonsWare. you made my day. !!